# Getting an error of Leaked MSIHANDLE() on Windows Server 2003 SP2 32 bit

Tags: memory-leaks, windows-installer, installshield

I have made a 32 bit installer in InstallShield. I'm installing this installer on Windows Server 2003 SP2 (32 bit). But I'm getting following error :

> MSI (c) (00:F0) [10:30:39:101]: Leaked MSIHANDLE (7) of type 790540 for thread 8904
>   MSI (c) (00:F0) [10:30:39:101]: Leaked MSIHANDLE (5) of type 790541 for thread 8904
>   MSI (c) (00:F0) [10:30:39:101]: Note: 1: 2769 2: ISSetupFilesExtract 3: 2 
>   Info 2769.
>   Custom Action ISSetupFilesExtract did not close 2 MSIHANDLEs.
>   Action ended 10:30:39: ISSetupFilesExtract. Return value 3.
>   MSI (c) (00:C4) [10:30:39:101]: Doing action: SetupCompleteError
>   Action 10:30:39: SetupCompleteError.
>   Action start 10:30:39: SetupCompleteError.

I searched a lot on this but couldn't found the root cause. Can anyone please help me to to find the main cause of this & please help me to find out the solution for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leaked handles are frequently seen in an installer log and not the source of your problem.   ISSetupFilesExtract is a Flexera written custom action so it's nothing your doing in your code.  I don't see enough information to know why it failed (Return value 3).   Can you post a little bit more?

Comment: christopher, some files are getting extracted.

1: Extracting Setup File: 
1: C:\DOCUME~1\AD760F~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\2\{294F912A-89C2-4A95-A2EB-A217FF5CBCA6}\_isconfig.xml 
MSI (c) (00:F0) [10:30:39:101]: Leaked MSIHANDLE (7) of type 790540 for thread 8904
MSI (c) (00:F0) [10:30:39:101]: Note: 1: 2769 2: ISSetupFilesExtract 3: 2 
Info 2769.Custom Action ISSetupFilesExtract did not close 2 MSIHANDLEs.
Action ended 10:30:39: ISSetupFilesExtract. Return value 3.

Comment: It looks like it crashed, that's why it didn't close the handles.  I'm not sure how you'd find out why the code is failing, maybe lack of privileges.

Comment: ProcessMonitor might reveal.  Those messages could be normal... I don't have a copy of InstallShield at the moment to do a mock up.  One of the reasons I like using WiX DTF  using(object) makes sure that IDispose is always called for me.